# Why is there a minimum character limit when editing an answer?

Tags: feature-request, editing

I tried to edit an incorrect answer but my edit was rejected because it had TOO FEW CHARACTERS!

This is silly.  If I'm fixing an equation from dy/dy to dy/dx, I shouldn't be forced to type nonsense just to satisfy your code.

[Projectile Motion - Arrow](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/projectile-motion-arrow)

Answer (score 6):

So don't type nonsense. Type something *useful*. Posts that are so close to absolute perfection that they can stand only tiny edits are *exceedingly* rare. Remember: every time you suggest an edit, someone else has to approve it - make sure you're making your edits substantial enough for them to bother with.

That said, once you gain 2K reputation points, you'll be able to make as many tiny edits as you care to. With a little bit of finesse, you'll even be able to make edits that don't change *anything at all*... Which is why we'd really like it if you got used to making more substantial edits now, so you don't fall into bad habits later: it's all too common to see users edit to fix one tiny error that bothers them, and leave ten others that they scanned too quickly to catch.

Answer (score 3):

When you ask a question, it starts out on the top of the homepage. As other questions are asked or have activity in them, they are put at the top of the page and your question is bumped down. This phenomenon is seen in other places too, like forums.

In forums, people will reply with a message that says "bump" for the sole purpose of bumping the thread to the top. But of course, "bump" is not an answer and would not be allowed here. So instead, you could edit your question and change it only slightly, and the action of editing puts the question back at the top of the homepage.

I've admittedly been guilty of this myself. It's actually an effective method of stirring up more views and answers on your question. And since it is so effective, people will naturally gravitate towards doing this.

I would like to see a "bump" link which facilitates this action, since it's only natural to want to foster more growth of your question, especially if it slipped through the cracks or maybe happened to be posted at the exact same time as 20 other questions and ended up far down the front page from the very start. But instead, it **appears** that Stack Exchange is attempting to fight it by setting a minimum edit count.

[Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) or [Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/), if you're reading this, I'd really like to see a blog post on why you are fighting the action of "bumping" a question! :)

Comment: isn't "bounty" the SO version of bumping? If you care enough to bump, don't you care enough to pay for an answer?

Comment: That's a good point! :)

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a forum. The inability of someone to return a question no one cares about to a position of prominence without either substantial edits or greater-than-usual remuneration is a _feature_ of SE, not a problem.

Comment: A question that garners no attention says nothing about the quality of the question, only of the people who happen to see the question and their ability to answer it (or interest in the question). This is a huge issue at Stack Overflow, where you can get unlucky and post a question 59 seconds before the homepage cache operation, and many other questions are added in those 59 seconds, thus putting your question at the bottom of the homepage from the get-go. This is not at all an uncommon occurrence during mid-day hours with SO's great popularity.

Comment: (Conversely, you can game the system by refreshing a few times to discover the 60-second mark, then making sure to post your question just before the next 60 seconds rolls around, putting your question at the very top of the homepage for a full 60 seconds - which is a lot of views during the busy times of the day; I am of course still referring to Stack Overflow in all this, since GDSE is not (yet) popular enough for this to be an issue)